# Tikkun Leil Shavuot for download

Tags: product-recommendation, shavuos, nusach-edot-hammizrach

Do we have any pdf of Tikkun Leil Shavuot (Nusach Edot haMizrach)?

If not is there any syllabus (which portions from Tanach,  Mishnayot, etc.) suggested by Chacham Ovadia Yosef or any other Sephardic Gadol?

Comment: I see an Ashkenazi one at http://www.hebrewbooks.org/10545